# Repeated multiplication of a square matrix and a column vector in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am very new to Mathematica and StackExchange, so pardon me if I am repeating a question that has already been answered. I am trying to use Mathematica to do the following: u[n+1] = A.u[n] where A is a square tridiagonal matrix and u[0] is a column vector. I want to be able to run this for any number of iterations, as many as I need. I then want to do a 3d plot of the results. My skills are very rudimentary. I would include what I already tried, but I havent been able to do any of it yet.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: For starters `NestList[A.#&, u[0],5]`

Comment: To keep the syntax close to what you have written: `u[n_] := u[n] = a.u[n - 1];` Then specify `a` and `u[1]` and ask for `u[10]` or `u[100]`.

Comment: Presumably, since `A` is a fixed matrix, you'll want to use the action form of `MatrixPower[]`: `MatrixPower[A, 5, u[0]]`.

Comment: By any chance, are you trying to demonstrate the power method here?

Comment: No, I am using the explicit finite difference method to solve the heat equation. I am comparing that to solving the heat equation using Fourier Series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dr. belisarius stated, `NestList[A.#&, u[0],5]` would work. (# and & are pure functions. [This guide may help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616))

If you want to keep the values of `u[1]`, `u[2]`, etc.:

```
u[n_] := u[n] = A . u[n - 1];
u[0] = {x, y, z}; (* your definition here *)
u[5]
```

The `u[n] =` part after `u[n_] :=` is optional (memoization), but it is a good practice to have it if you have a recursion formula. It saves memory by preventing redundant computations.

Then for a 3D plot: (replace `10` with whatever number of point you want)

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[u[n], {n, 0, 10}]
```

-

Edit: A useful function to use could be [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html). It performs a given operation a given number of times and outputs all of the steps. For example, `NestList[f, x, 3]` gives `{x, f[x], f[f[x]], f[f[f[x]]]}`.

Use this instead if you do not want to keep the values of `u[n]`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 NestList[Function[vector, A . vector], u[0], 10]
]
```

You could replace `Function[...]` with its pure-function counterpart, `A.#&`.

Comment: I would really like the 3d plot to be a contour plot that shows each iteration, u[1], u[2], u[3], ... progressing through time, not stacked on top of one another. Not sure how to do this in this instance.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = RotationMatrix[Pi/20, {0, 1, 1}] // N;
start = {1, 0, 0};
Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrowheads[.03], Arrow@Partition[#, 2, 1], Red, 
    PointSize[Medium], Point@#, Green, PointSize[.03], 
    Point@start}] &@NestList[a.# &, start, 40]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]